# why setState does'nt change the "editing" key to true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

The edit function does not change the editing in state to true.

I don't know what to do:

```
class Note extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        editing: false

    }

}
/**edit() {
    this.setState = ({
        editing: true
    })**/

}

remove() {
    alert ("removed")
}

save() {
    alert ("saved")
}

renderForm() {
    return (
        <div className="note">
            <form>
                <textarea/>
                <button onClick={this.save}> click  </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

renderDisplay() {
    return (
        <div className="note">
            <p> Learn React </p>
            <span>
                <button onClick={this.edit} id="edit"> Edit </button>
                <button onClick={this.remove} id="remove"> Delete </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}

render() {
    return this.state.editing ? this.renderForm() : this.renderDisplay()
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You should change this:

```
this.setState = ({
  editing: true
})
```

to this:

```
this.setState({
  editing: true
})
```

Also, you should bind `edit` method or use an arrow function instead. It's required because in JavaScript function context is defined while calling the function, not while defining it.

[Here you can check an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/a0n9gpko/)